# Prove a property of finding the same elements in two lists

Tags: coq

I'm new to Coq. I have a function `findshare` which finds the same elements in two lists. Lemma `sameElements` proves that the result of function `findshare` on the concatenation of two lists is equal to the concatenation of the results of the function applied to each one of them. I'm a bit stuck in proving lemma `sameElements`.

```
Require Import List .
Fixpoint findshare(s1 s2: list nat): list nat:=
      match s1 with
        | nil => nil
        | v :: tl =>
           if ( existsb  (Nat.eqb v)  s2)
            then v :: findshare tl s2
            else findshare tl s2
      end.

 Lemma sameElements l1 l2 tl :
  (findshare tl (l1++l2)) =
  (findshare tl (l1))++ (findshare tl (l2)).
Proof.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having trouble because the statement you have is not quite correct: it entails a contradiction. More precisely, it implies that `[1; 2] = [2; 1]`:

```
Require Import List .
Fixpoint findshare(s1 s2: list nat): list nat:=
      match s1 with
        | nil => nil
        | v :: tl =>
           if ( existsb  (Nat.eqb v)  s2)
            then v :: findshare tl s2
            else findshare tl s2
      end.

Lemma sameElements l1 l2 tl :
  (findshare tl (l1++l2)) =
  (findshare tl (l1))++ (findshare tl (l2)).
Admitted.

Import ListNotations.

Lemma contra : False.
Proof.
pose proof (sameElements [1] [2] [2;1]).
simpl in H.
discriminate.
Qed.
```

You should be able to prove the lemma by swapping `tl` with `l1`, `l2` and `l1 ++ l2`, and proceeding by induction on `l1`.

Comment: That's a good point. Could I use another operator instead of ``=`` in ``sameElements`` ( an operator that returns true when element are same but in different orders)  to prove it?

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't an operator available in Coq to express what you want directly, but you can define one (e.g. `almost_equal l1 l2 = forall x, In x l1 <-> In x l2`).